# BigInteger Parsing scientific notation with an exponent larger than 1000 results in 9999

Tags: c#, biginteger

I've been struggling with why this code seems to work the way it does. To me it looks like a bug in the `BigInteger` class but I could be wrong.

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Globalization;

BigInteger result;
if (!BigInteger.TryParse("2.36e6007", NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, null, out result)) result = 0;
Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString("0.00e0000"));
```

I consistently get `2.36e9999` as the result, regardless of what number I use the order of magnitude is always `9999`.  I'm unsure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong here. I tried a breakpoint after the parse and inspected the value and it does indeed have `9999` zeroes so if it's a bug it's in `BigInteger.TryParse`

Comment: "regardless of what number I use the mantissa is always 9999." You mean the _exponent_?

Comment: Here is [your problem](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/Common/src/System/Globalization/FormatProvider.Number.cs#L495) anything over 1000 gets an exponent of 9999

Comment: Now that we know that, any solution would depend on what you are actually trying to do or specifically what you need to do.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely it, thanks. Essentially what I'm trying to do is parse a bunch of these large numbers in this same format 0.00e0000 so that I can utilize them as BigIntegers for comparison and math operations. Perhaps I can come up with a clever way to break them down parse in pieces because I don't think the problem is fundamentally with the BigInteger class but with this implementation of TryParse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work isn't so much a bug *per se*, as much as it's a limitation in [`ParseNumber`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/Common/src/System/Globalization/FormatProvider.Number.cs#L495)

```
if (exp > 1000)
{
   exp = 9999;
   while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
   {
      ch = *++p;
   }
}
```

As you can see, any *exponent* over `1000` will default to an exponent of `9999`.

One approach (depending on your needs) is to parse the exponent yourself and to create the `BigInteger` from its constituent parts. The downside of this is it won't deal with any variation outside its very narrow scope (you will need to add pepper and salt to taste). It will also likely be a lot slower.

**Given**

```
public static (decimal multiplier, int exponent) Decompose(string value)
{
   var split = value.Split('e');
   return (decimal.Parse(split[0]), int.Parse(split[1]));
}
public static int GetDecimalPlaces(decimal value) 
   => BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(value)[3])[2];

public static BigInteger ParseExtended(string value)
{
   var (multiplier, exponent) = Decompose(value);

   var decimalPlaces = GetDecimalPlaces(multiplier);
   var power = (int) Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);

   return (BigInteger.Pow(10, exponent) * (int) (multiplier * power)) / power;
}
```

**Usage**

```
Console.WriteLine(ParseExtended("2.36e6007").ToString("0.00e0000"));
```

**Output**

```
2.36e6007
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ahmkFG)

<sub>***Note** : this is not a solution to every problem, it lacks a suitable amount of fault tolerance, and is only an example of a possible solution.*</sub>